# Does an empty stomach cause gas?

Tags: medical-science

[This article](http://www.healthguidance.org/entry/15634/1/Instant-Gas-Relief--Causes-and-Cures.html) claims:

> However on the other end of the spectrum having your stomach empty can also cause gas as that empty stomach area fills up with air.

Is this claim true or just an old wives tale?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is probably not appropriate for this site, perhaps the biology one?  Questions on this site are usually about notable claims that one is skeptical about, rather than direct biological explanations.

Comment: @MarkRogers I am skeptical about why an empty stomach can cause gas when there is no reactions between stomach acid and food since food is not present.

Comment: @MarkRogers, However, I would still appreciate if you move this question to the biology site if it does not belong here.

Comment: There's a biology site [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/), moving the question to that site is not one of my available options here.  A moderator maybe along to edit, move, or adjust your question.

Comment: Given there are no upvotes and no answers, the easiest way to migrate is to copy-and-paste this to Biology.SE and delete it here. No need for Skeptics & Biology moderators to get involved.

Comment: I see this question as being valid on both sites though. It, after all, is a claim that warrants skepticism.

Comment: The questions "does it happen" and "what is the evidence that it does or doesn't happen" is on-topic here. The question "why does it happen" is not on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

The article is partially correct. According to WebMD there are 9 conditions associated with hunger and increased passing gas.

> ## Hunger and Increased passing gas
>
> There are 9 conditions associated with hunger and increased passing gas. The links below will provide you with more detailed information on these medical conditions from the WebMD Symptom Checker and help provide a better understanding of causes and treatment of these related conditions.
>
> ### Constipation (child)
>
> Constipation is having less than three bowel movements a week, causing hard stools, abdominal pain and more.
>
> ### Constipation (adult)
>
> Constipation is having less than three bowel movements a week, causing hard stools, abdominal pain and more.
>
> ### Gas pains
>
> Belching or passing gas clears gas from the digestive tract, but when gas is stuck it causes abdominal pain.
>
> ### Irritable bowel syndrome
>
> Irritable bowel syndrome is a common condition that causes painful spasms and cramping in the large intestine.
>
> ### Lactose intolerance
>
> Lactose intolerance, or the inability to digest lactose, leads to gas, bloating, and other symptoms.
>
> ### Giardiasis
>
> Giardiasis is an infection of the small intestine causing diarrhea, gas, bloating, nausea and stomach cramps.
>
> ### Insulin reaction (hypoglycemia)
>
> An insulin reaction is the result of low blood sugar and causes anxiety, hunger, shaking, dizziness, and more.
>
> ### Low blood sugar (hypoglycemia)
>
> Low blood sugar, or low glucose levels, causes shakiness, anxiety, clammy skin, irritability, hunger, and more.
>
> ### Malnutrition
>
> Malnutrition occurs when the body isn't getting enough nutrients; sometimes the condition is life-threatening.

[Hunger and Increased passing gas](http://symptomchecker.webmd.com/multiple-symptoms?symptoms=hunger%7Cincreased-passing-gas&symptomids=547%7C176&locations=66%7C24)

However, [correlation is not causation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation), and in most of these cases being hungry is not identified as the (direct) cause of increased passing gas, but as a common symptom.

Comment: The source you provided is authoritative and unreferenced. Do you have any studies to include?

Comment: I don't think they are necessary. As you state, the source is already authoritative, probably more so than single studies.